# Why getPurchaseHistory method is not present in IInAppBillingService.aidl even if it is documented?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have requirement in which I would like to have the receipt of my purchase which is already consumed. So using of method getPurchases is ruled out because it only provides info of purchases which are owned and not consumed.
I can see documentation of getPurchaseHistory which can give all purchase history of all the purchases in 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getPurchaseHistory

But its api is not present in IInAppBillingService.aidl

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/551a178e52baf60cc6e1f9cb6f40767b8453655a/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the page you linked:

> [getPurchaseHistory] is available in version 6 and later of the in-app billing API.

However, the latest published version of the In-App Billing API, as seen in the SDK Manager, is version 5. This can also been seen in the [version notes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html).

I suspect when version 6 does become available, it will indeed include `getPurchaseHistory`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest version of an AIDL file which contains this method here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl

Plus newly released Play Billing library also [has a method](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchaseHistoryResponseListener)) to get purchase history.